# Take the last element of a lazy enumerator

Tags: ruby, optimization, lazy-evaluation

I have a function like this:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.take_while {|n|(n**2+ 1*n+41).prime?}.force[-1]
```

I'm using this as an optimisation exercise. This works fine, but it has a memory order O(n) as it will create the entire array and then take the last element.

I am trying to get this without building the entire list, hence the lazy enumerator. I can't think of anything other than using a `while` loop.

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.take_while {|n|(n**2+ 1*n+41).prime?}.last.force
```

Is there a way to do this in space order O(1) rather than O(n) with enumerators?

EDIT: lazy isn't necessary here for the example to work, but I thought it might be more useful to reduce the space complexity of the function?

Comment: How is this different than removing `lazy` and `force`?  39 both ways.  Why `1*n`?

Comment: Good point, lazy isn't necessary in this case as we are using take_while, I'm just generally used to using it when dealing with infinity, about to edit question to reflect this.

Comment: Err... You're using enumerators already, no?

Comment: Yep, wanting to do it without building a list, this has been clarified in the question now. :)

Comment: Note that there can be a benefit to actually building the array, depending in what you're truly doing: with it, the garbage collector is less likely to kick in while you're in the middle of finding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just don't want to save the entire array:

```
(0..1.0/0).find {|n| !(n**2+n+41).prime?} - 1
```

`1.0/0` is the same as `Float::INFINITY`.  I used it in case you hadn't seen it.  So far as I know, neither is preferable.

My first thought clearly was overkill:

```
def do_it
  e = (0..1.0/0).to_enum
  loop do
    n = e.peek
    return e.inspect unless (n**2+n+41).prime?
    e.next
  end
end

do_it
```

Comment: exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, I wasn't aware of e.peek for enumerators

Comment: @Denis, `[Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)` returns the first value `n` in the block for which the expression evaluates `true` (not an array).  In this case that's `40`, but we want the last one that;  hence `-1`.  When you have a question like this one, you should get in the habit of checking the docs and/or trying it in irb.  Not a criticism, a suggestion.

Comment: yes, this edit is the kind of thing I was looking for (why I posed the question in the first place), I knew there'd be an enumerable that did what I was looking for, I just couldn't find it in the docs, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Use inject to hold on to the current value instead of building an array.

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.take_while {|n|(n**2+ 1*n+41).prime?}.inject{|acc,n| n }
```

Note that you *must* use `lazy` otherwise `inject` will build an intermediate array.

**Verifying**

To see what happens if you don't use lazy, run the following after restarting ruby & running the non-lazy version. It will return arrays that "look like" the intermediate array.

```
ObjectSpace.enum_for(:each_object, Array).each_with_object([]) {|e, acc|
  acc << e if e.size == 40 and e.first == 0
}
```

The non-lazy version will return:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]
```

Re-doing the test with lazy will return an empty array.